# Exclude current directory from tar

Tags: shell, tar

I'm trying to exclude the current directory from the tarball without excluding its contents, because when I extract it out using the `-k` flag I get an exit status of 1 and a message

```
./: Already exists
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

How do I do this? I've tried the `--exclude` flag but that excludes the contents also (rightly so). I'm trying to code this for both the OSX/BSD and GNU versions of tar.

## Test case:

```
# Setup
mkdir /tmp/stackoverflow
cd /tmp/stackoverflow
mkdir dir 
touch dir/file

# Create
tar cCf dir dir.tar .

# List contents
tar tf dir.tar
```

gives

```
./
./file
```

showing that the current directory `./` is in the tar. This would be fine, but when I do the following:

```
mkdir dir2
tar xkfC dir.tar dir2
```

due to the `-k` flag, I get an exit code of 1 and the message

```
./: Already exists
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the current directory you can create your archive on this way:

```
tar cf /path/to/dir.tar ./*
```

use `./*`instead of `.`, this will not match current directory (`.`) and therefore not include in the archive

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
cd dir
tar cf ../dir.tar *
```

The extra cd is to replace the use of the `-C` flag, so that we can use a glob. The `GLOBIGNORE` ignores the current directory, but also sets `shopt -s dotglob` implicitly to include hidden files. Using `*` instead of `./*` means that the tar file listing doesn't list `./file`, but instead lists it as `file`. The entire listing of the tar is:

```
file
```